# Netbeans New project wizard does not show Maven Web Application

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, netbeans-8

I have read the other questions regarding this! So this is not another duplicate.

When using the "new project wizard" in Netbeans 8.0 I choose **Maven** but then I can't choose **Web Application**. It's simply not displayed. So I asked google, and it told me **to install JAVE EE**. And **I did** but still no Web Application under the Maven Catergory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your Netbeans distribution does not contain JavaEE plugin. 
You can install it via **Tools>Plugins>Available Plugins** and search for **Java EE**

Update your plugin!!

Comment: Read my question I did install JAVA EE!

Comment: You need to install JavaEE plugin for Netbeans

Comment: Did you enabled the plugin?

Comment: Turns out that you also need to update your plugins!