# Can't create Maven Web Application project in netbeans 9.0

Tags: netbeans

I'm happy that netbeans 9.0 has just launched, but I can't create a Maven Web Application project in netbeans 9.0.

There is no Web Application option to select in Maven category when creating a new project.

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001888/netbeans-new-project-wizard-does-not-show-maven-web-application), but there is no available plugin for Java EE.

I have Java 10 enabled system wide.

Before netbeans 9.0, I was using netbeans 8.2 with Java 8 and had no problem.

Comment: See this answer to [How to get Netbeans 9 to deploy a valid webapp on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567033/2985643). Although the problem is completely different to yours, the solution is the same: you need to add and then install the Java EE plugins on NB 9. After doing that **File > New Project... > Maven > Web Application** should be available.

Comment: That fixed it, but it turned out that it doesn't allow me to use or select Java EE 8 option. I was looking forward to using Java EE 8, so it's a bit of a bummer. I also realized that Payara 5 doesn't support java 10 yet, so I will keep using netbeans 8 with Java 8 for now. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: OK, understood. FYI, [Netbeans 9 was formally released](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) two days ago, but it won't do anything that you can't already do with your beta version. Also, there is a [GitHub lab on using EE 8 with NetBeans 8.2](https://github.com/javaee/j1-hol) though I haven't tried it.

Comment: The netbeans I was mentioning the whole time in this post was the officially launched complete version of netbeans 9.0 that was released a few days ago. Neither 9.0 Beta nor 9.0 RC1.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is a big issue with **Netbeans 9** and **10**, but this is a way to handler for now:

1. Go to `Tools` > `Plugins` > `Settings`
2. Active `Netbeans 8.2 Plugin
   Portal`
3. Wait for download content.
4. Then go to `Available Plugins` Tab.
5. Press `Check for Newest`
6. Search for `web` or `EE`
7. Check Install box for `Java EE`
8. Press `Install`
9. Restart IDE.
10. *Yeah... we done!*

[image: Activate Update center]

[image: Install plugins]

FYI: https://vorozco.com/blog/2018/2018-07-30-NetBeans-9-JavaEE-JakartaEE.html